# $http.post: Large files do not work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ng-file-upload, body-parser

I am trying to upload files through my web app using the following code.

View:

```
  <form name="uploadForm" class="form-horizontal col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="file" ng-model="rsdCtrl.viewData.file" name="file"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Controller:

```
function uploadFile(){
  if (uploadForm.file.$valid && file) {
    return uploadService.upload(vd.file, "Convictions Calculator", "PCCS").then(function(response){
      /* Some stuff */
    }).catch(handleServiceError);
  }
}
```

uploadService:

```
(function (){
'use strict';
angular.module('cica.common').service('uploadService', ['$http', '$routeParams', uploadService]);

function uploadService($http, $routeParams) {

    this.upload = function (file, name, type) {
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('document', file);
        fd.append('jobId', $routeParams.jobId);
        fd.append('documentRename', name);
        fd.append('documentType', type);

        return $http.post('/document/upload', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).catch(function(err){
            handleHttpError('Unable to upload document.', err);
        });
    };
  }
})();
```

routes.js:

```
    'POST /document/upload': {controller: 'DocumentController', action: 'uploadDocument'},
```

DocumentController:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  uploadDocument: function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.allParams());   //Inserted as part of debugging
    const params = req.allParams();
    req.file('document').upload({
        // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~100MB
        maxBytes: 100000000
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
        else if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
            return res.serverError('No file was uploaded');
        } else {
            const filePath = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
            const filename = uploadedFiles[0].filename;
            return fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.serverError(err);
                } else {
                    const jobId = params.jobId;
                    const jobVars =
                        {
                            filePath: results.filePath,
                            fileName: params.documentRename,
                            fileType: params.documentType
                        };
                    return DocumentService.uploadConvictions(req.session.sessionId, jobId, jobVars).then(function (response) {
                        return res.send("Document uploaded.");
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        return res.serverError(err);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
```

If I upload a .jpeg (around 11kB) the upload works exactly as expected, however, if I try to upload a larger .jpeg (around 170kB) it falls over. There is no immediate error thrown/caught though, what happens is the formData object created in the upload service seems to lose its data. If I breakpoint on its value, it returns empty for the larger file, which eventually causes an error when the function tries to use these variables further on. Is there some kind of limit set to the size of a file you can upload via this method, or have I configured this incorrectly?

Comment: _"the formData object created in the upload service seems to lose its data"_ How are you determining that? Note when logging the FormData object directly to the console or viewing it in the debugger you won't see the data directly on the object, you have to use the `get()` method or use the various iterators. Check the actual request in the Network tab to see if the file is included in the request body (usually shown at the bottom of the request info tab)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I inserted a line "Console.log(req.allParams());" in the documentUpload function of the DocumentController. For smaller files it returned the parameters and their values as expected. For a larger file, this returned empty.

Also, the network tab shows the correct values being sent, but my console.log has no values.

Comment: I've edited the code to show this.

Comment: Are you using `bodyParser` as middleware?

Comment: How are you getting the file from the `<input>` element? The `ng-model` directive doesn't work when the input is `type="file"`.

Answer (score 4):

I take the chance and assume you are using `bodyParser` as middleware. bodyParser has a default `limit` of 100kb. Look at `node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js` :

```
var limit = typeof options.limit !== 'number'
    ? bytes(options.limit || '100kb')
    : options.limit
```

You can change the limit in your `app.js` by

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: 1048576 } )); //1mb
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I think you've cracked it, I'm currently trying to verify. I'm using sails, so I believe I need to put this in my config/http.js file, but I think sails uses 'skipper' which overwrites this, so I'm trying to work out exactly how to implement your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I use this workaround...

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" value="" id="uploadNewAttachment"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

In JavaScript you can upload files using the 3 method:

```
var binBlob = []; // If you use AngularJS, better leave it out of the DOM
var fi = document.getElementById('uploadNewAttachment');
fi.onchange = function(e) {
    r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function(ev) {
        binBlob[binBlob.length] = ev.target.result;
    };
    //r.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]); // Very slow due to Base64 encoding
    //r.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]); // Slow and may result in incompatible chars with AJAX and PHP side
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]); // Fast and Furious!
};
$(fi).trigger('click');
```

What we have, javascript side is an Uint8Array of byte with values from 0 to 255 (or a Int8Array -128 to 127).

When this Array is sent via AJAX, it is "maximized" using signs and commas. This increases the number of total bytes sent.

EX:

```
[123, 38, 98, 240, 136, ...] or worse: [-123, 38, -81, 127, -127, ...]
```

As you can see, the number of characters transmitted is oversized.

We can instead proceed as follows:

Before send data over AJAX, do this:

```
var hexBlob = [];
for(var idx=0; idx<binBlob.length; idx++) {
    var ex = Array.from(new Uint8Array(binBlob[idx]));;
    for(var i=0;i<ex.length; i++) {
        ex[i] = ex[i].toString(16).padStart(2,'0');
    };
    hexBlob[idx] = ex.join('');
}
```

What you have now, is a string of hex bytes in chars!

Ex:

```
3a05f4c9...
```

that use less chars of a signed or unsigned javascript array.

**PHP:**
On the PHP side, you can decode this array, directly to binary data, simply using:

```
for($idx=0; $idx<=count($hexBlob); $idx++) {
    // ...
    $binData = pack('H*',$hexBlob[$idx]);
    $bytesWritten = file_put_contents($path.'/'.$fileName[$idx], $binData);
    //...
}
```

This solution worked very well for me.

Comment: This is a very nice first answer. I appreciate that you broke up your code into multiple blocks and interspersed it with explanations of what you’re doing. Thank you for taking the time to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) when Uploading Large Files<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959286/angular-upload-error-405-when-sending-formdata/40968053#40968053)</sup>

The [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) encodes data in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which add 33% extra overhead.

Instead of sending `FormData`, send the file directly:

```
app.service('fileUpload', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (url, file) {
        ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶f̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶F̶o̶r̶m̶D̶a̶t̶a̶(̶)̶;̶
        ̶f̶d̶.̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶d̶(̶'̶f̶i̶l̶e̶'̶,̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶)̶;̶
        ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶$̶h̶t̶t̶p̶.̶p̶o̶s̶t̶(̶u̶r̶l̶,̶ ̶f̶d̶,̶ ̶{̶
        return $http.post(url, file, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        });
    };
});
```

When the browser sends `FormData`, it uses `'Content-Type': multipart/formdata` and encodes each part using base64.

When the browser sends a file (or blob), it sets the content type to the MIME-type of the file (or blob). It puts the binary data in the body of the request.

---

### How to enable `<input type="file">` to work with `ng-model`<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file-with-directive-demo/43074638#43074638)</sup>

Out of the box, the `ng-model` directive does not work with `input type="file"`. It needs a directive:

```
app.directive("selectNgFile", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files[0];
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Usage:

```html
<input type="file" select-ng-file ng-model="rsdCtrl.viewData.file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for commenting. You're quite correct, it's all good information but it's not the root of my problem. I'm using a module called ng-file-upload. I trimmed my html down quite a bit as I have various lines of validation and such that I felt took away from my question. In doing so I've deleted "ngf-select" from the input tag, which uses the module.