# How to change the default configuration of Sails JS middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, middleware, body-parser

I am trying to alter the settings of a Sails JS app and am having a bit of bother passing a parameter to the body-Parser in order to change the default settings.

I previously had the issue described here: [Posting larger files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360780/http-post-larger-files-do-not-work/51361786#51361786)

I believe this problem has been answered correctly by changing the default 'limit' option, as a 100kb default size minus the 33% overhead from the formData object is pretty consistent with what size of file I can/can't send. So the solution proposed was this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: 1048576 } ));
```

but am unable to implement the solution in my Sails app. I have read through the [Sails Documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-http#?customizing-the-body-parser) on changing the middleware settings, and tried the following in my config/http.js file...

**First attempt - wrapper**

```
/**
 * HTTP Server Settings
 * (sails.config.http)
 */

module.exports.http = {

middleware: {

  order: [
   'startRequestTimer',
   'cookieParser',
   'session',
   'refreshSessionCookie',
   'bodyParserInit',
   'bodyParser',
   'handleBodyParserError',
   'compress',
   'methodOverride',
   'poweredBy',
   '$custom',
   'requestLogger',
   'router',
   'www',
   'favicon',
   '404',
   '500'
  ],

   bodyParserInit   : (function (){
     let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

     return bodyParser( { extended: true, limit: 1073741824 } )
   })(),

  )
},

// cache: 31557600000

};
```

**Second attempt - overwrite**

```
/**
 * HTTP Server Settings
 * (sails.config.http)
 */

module.exports.http = {

middleware: {

  order: [
   'startRequestTimer',
   'cookieParser',
   'session',
   'refreshSessionCookie',
   //'bodyParserInit',
   'bodyParser',
   'handleBodyParserError',
   'compress',
   'methodOverride',
   'poweredBy',
   '$custom',
   'requestLogger',
   'router',
   'www',
   'favicon',
   '404',
   '500'
  ],

   bodyParser: (function _configureBodyParser(){
      let skipper = require('skipper');
      let middlewareFn = skipper({
          limit: 1073741824,
      });
      return middlewareFn;
   })(),

  )
},

// cache: 31557600000

};
```

However, neither attempt solved my issue as the limit still appears to be set 100kb regardless of anything I've done. How do I implement this correctly, so that the body parser accepts files of up to 50kb? I presume either I am not configuring this correctly or something else is overwriting what I've done.

**EDIT**: I'm using Sails version > 12.0.X

Comment: Did you take a look at *Skipper*'s FAQ? https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#how-do-i-customize-the-skipper-options-in-my-sails-app

Comment: Yes, it suggests something similar to what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sails > v0.12.x:

```
    module.exports.http = {

      middleware: {
          // ... options
          bodyParser: require('skipper')({ limit: 1073741824 })
      }

    };
```

For sails < v0.12.x:

```
    module.exports.http = {

        middleware: {
            order: [
                // ... options
                // 'bodyParser', <- remove bodyParser
                'skipper', // <-- add skipper
            ],
            skipper: require('skipper')({ limit: 1073741824 })
        }

    };
```

Here's the [link to the documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#how-do-i-customize-the-skipper-options-in-my-sails-app).

Comment: thanks for your response. I have read the documentation, and your answer is very similar to my second attempt. I've tried again as you have written it and it hasn't worked, I am still only able to upload files under 100kb.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you have looked at this [Sails GitHubIssue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2653)

Seems very much related and from what it seems few people have made it work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have looked at this, and tried various solutions posted on that thread, but none of the above appear to be working for me. I did manage to replicate some of their errors, but nothing worked as expected.